# Electron multiple window IPC architecture

Tags: javascript, electron, software-design

I am planing to build a software with `electron` which should have many different windows. I already read a book and study the documentation to get familiar with the electron `ipc module` and how it works.

This concept works for me, with a manageable number of windows but even more windows my application gets even more confusing it becomes.

I am also new to javascript and `Prototype-based object-oriented programming`

I am trying to imagin how could i build a large software without loosing the overview of main.js.

The problem is that the main.js need specific ipc methods for every single window. I think of a solution in which i may hold the ipc methods in other javascript files with relevant names.

now i need to do in main.js for example:

```
ipcMain.on('window1-call1' .. {
  //do stuff
}

ipcMain.on('window1-call2' .. {
  //do stuff
} 

ipcMain.on('window2-call1' .. {
      //do stuff
}

and so on .....
```

Here is one example from my `main.js`, `preload.js` and `renderer.js`
to show how i build up a simple IPC example:

```
//main.js 

ipc.on('open-directory-dialog', function (event) {
  dialog.showOpenDialog(mainWindow, {
    title: 'Select a image...',
    properties: ['openFile'],
    defaultPath: '/home',
    buttonLabel: "Select...",
    filters: [
    { name: 'Images', extensions: ['jpg', 'png', 'gif'] }
    ]
    }, function (files) {
      if (files) event.sender.send('selectedItem', files)
      })
  })
```

```
//preload.js

window.ipcFiledialog = function (channel) {
  ipcRenderer.send('open-directory-dialog')
}

//callback
ipcRenderer.on('selectedItem', function (event, path) {
  setSelectedItem(path)
})
```

```
//renderer.js

selectDirBtn.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    window.ipcFiledialog('open-directory-dialog')
    })

function setSelectedItem (files) {
    document.getElementById('selectedItem').innerHTML = files
}
```

With this approach i have to create every window in main.js (this will grow the main.js) and make sure i call a specific ipc method for the right window.
The callback method needs to call also a specific method for every window.

So i would need many methods and this construct does not look very flexible.

**Is there any best practice to prevent main.js to grow into the “infinite” and get more flexible ipc methods ?**

Comment: How many windows do you envisage, and will they each be doing some different task, or do they all do the same task (e.g. an image viewer, with one window for each photo being opened)?

Comment: I think about 20 - 30 windows. Every window should do other tasks. I want to build a small bill softw

Comment: @Danloc How are you going with this? Have you resolved your problem?